# How to auto activate DAGS in airflow

Tags: airflow

I'm new to airflow and I wonder how can I have DAGs to auto-activate after being loaded.

[image]

I mean the switches, they are off by default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For All Dags**:

Change `dags_are_paused_at_creation` to `False` in `airflow.cfg`.

You will find it in `[core]` section.

```
[core]
# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = False
```

**Single DAG**:
If you do not want to change it for all DAGs, you can set `is_paused_upon_creation=True` when creating DAG object.

Example:

```py
dag = DAG(
    DAG_NAME, 
    schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *', 
    default_args=default_args, 
    is_paused_upon_creation=True)
```

Comment: or, is there a programmatic way to activate them?

Comment: @gotch4 Updated answer with that as well.

Comment: you are the HERO