# airflow toggle not turning on when airflow is lanched

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

In airflow, by default all the toggles of the dags are turned off. I want all the toggles of all the dags to be turned on when I launch the airflow.

Based on the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57558493/how-to-auto-activate-dags-in-airflow), I changed `dags_are_paused_at_creation` to `False` in `airflow.cfg` in my `$AIRFLOW_HOME`.

Then I launched webserver and scheduler in 2 different terminals using-
`airflow webserver -p 8080` and `airflow scheduler`.

But still the toggles are off in the UI. I need to turn them on manually which I don't want. I want the toggles to be turned `on` when I launch the airflow. I have attached some screenshots. Please help.

Config:

[image: config]

UI:

[image: UI]

Comment: Please refer to this airflow discussion thread. It says that applying the global setting will apply to newly created DAGs ( not to the DAGs that are already present) https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/30624#discussioncomment-5604276

Comment: Thanks it worked when created a new dag.